# How to vertically align before text inside absolute element?

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to vertically align middle text written in `:before` CSS. I can't figure this out.

Seems like a duplicate, but I already tried all I found. Maybe I miss wrote it, but I think this case hasn't been covered yet: absolute element + before text.

Here is what I have so far:

```css
.element {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  height: inherit;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.element:before {
  content: "Some text to align vertically";
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="element"></div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

display flex or table will easily do :

```css
html,
body,
.element {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin:0;
  border-collapse:collapse;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.element {
  position: absolute;
  display: table;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  height: inherit;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.element:before {
  content: "Some text to align vertically";
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="element"></div>
```

flex

```css
.element {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  height: inherit;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}
.element:before {
  content: "Some text to align vertically";
  }
```

```html
<div class="element"></div>
```

or

```css
.element {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  height: inherit;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.element:before {
  content: "Some text to align vertically";
  margin:auto;
  }
```

```html
<div class="element"></div>
```